# Determine a rational number $r$ such that $0\lt \sqrt2 - r \lt 10^{-5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine a rational number $r$ such that $0\lt \sqrt2 - r \lt 10^{-5}$.

Any hint, please?

Comment: Find the decimal approximation of $\sqrt 2$ to the desired number of decimal places.

Comment: Alternatively, use the sequence $7/5, 41/29, 239/169...$

Comment: Thanks, guys! I didn't think it was that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating the inequality gives
$$-\sqrt2\lt -r\lt10^{-5}-\sqrt2$$
$$\sqrt2\gt r\gt\sqrt2-10^{-5}$$
So we need to find a number within $10^{-5}$ of $\sqrt2$.
Use a sequence which approximates $\sqrt2$ with rational numbers, such as
$$\dfrac 1 1, \dfrac 3 2, \dfrac 7 5, \dfrac {17} {12}, \dfrac {41} {29}, \dfrac {99} {70}, \dfrac {239} {169}, \dfrac {577} {408}, \ldots$$

I am going to use $\frac{577}{408}$. It is larger than $\sqrt2$ by around $2\times10^{-6}$, so subtract $10^{-5}$ so it is less than $\sqrt2$ and fits within the boundries of the inequality. 
So a solution for $r$ is $$r=\frac{577}{408}-10^{-5}$$
Writing as a fraction
$$r=\frac{7212449}{5100000}$$

Comment: How have you figured that sequence?

Comment: Look up "continued fractions"

Comment: @Miguel I searched "sequence approximating sqrt2". I found it on [this website](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequence_of_Best_Rational_Approximations_to_Square_Root_of_2).